# Laplace Transform (and Radius of Convergence?): $e^{-s \infty} = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laplace-transform

When taking Laplace transforms such as

$$\int_{t_0}^\infty e^{-st},$$

we subsequently get

$$-\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^\infty_{t_0}.$$

Now, my textbook author will just claim that $e^{-s \infty} = 0$, leaving us with the solution $\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0}$. However, since $s$ is a complex number, this seems exceedingly handy-wavy to me. I find this unacceptable, and I want to understand the mathematics of what's going on here.

In my research, I *have* encountered the concept of **radius of convergence**, and I suspect that this has something to do with what's going on here. However, doing a search for keywords, my textbook does not address the radius of convergence in any direct context of the Laplace transform, but rather later in the context of the Taylor/Laurent series.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain what's going on here. Please note that I have not studied complex analysis - just pieces of it - so please provide careful explanations.

Comment: Look for "region of convergence", not radius.

Comment: @N.S. Already did; there are no results for "region of convergence" in my textbook.

Comment: Is your textbook a math or a physics textbook? :)

Comment: @N.S. Math by a Professor of Applied Mathematics in the U.K.

Comment: Look back to the definition of the Laplace transform, and around it. Even if the words "region of convergence" are not stated explicitely, the author probably writes something along the lines "the formula is understood to hold for all $s$ for which the limit exists" or "the formula is understood to hold whenever when it makes sense" or something like that.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the function $\exp(z)$?

Comment: This is in some sense  similat to $\int \frac{1}{x}= \ln |x|$, note that this formula does not hold on any interval containing $0$, and the problem becomes even "messier" over $\mathbb C$. Also, this is not the general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ on its domain, it is only the general antiderivative on an interval in its domain... But everyone "knows" that this is the convention.

Comment: @N.S. Just checked again, and all it says is that "... the variable $s$ often has to take complex values." Mentions nothing more about it.

Comment: @snar Yes, Euler's formula.

Comment: @snar Note that the integral is divergent even when $s=-1$, so real vs complex is not the issue... The issue is the convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said

$$\int_{t_0}^\infty e^{-st}dt =  \lim_{r \to +\infty}-\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^r_{t_0}$$

Now, the RHS is convergent if and only if $\mbox{Re}(s) >0$.

---

**Added details**

$$\lim_{r \to +\infty}-\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^r_{t_0}=
\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0} - \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s}  e^{-sr} \\
=\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0}- \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s}  e^{-\mbox{Re}{(s)}r} \left(\cos( -\mbox{Im}(s)r)+i \sin(-\mbox{Im}(s)r) \right)
$$

Now, if

- $\mbox{Re}{(s)} >0$ then $\lim_{r \to \infty} e^{-\mbox{Re}{(s)}r} =0$ and by the squeeze theorem
  $$ \lim_{r \to +\infty}-\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-sr} \right]^r_{t_0} = \dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0}$$
- $\mbox{Re}{(s)} =0$ then 
  $$-\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^r_{t_0}=  \left(\cos( -\mbox{Im}(s)r)+i \sin(-\mbox{Im}(s)r) \right)$$
  does not have a limit at $r =\infty$.
- $\mbox{Re}{(s)} < 0$ then $\lim_{r \to \infty} e^{-\mbox{Re}{(s)}r} =\infty$ and the limit 
  $$ \lim_{r \to +\infty} - \dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^r_{t_0}$$
  cannot be finite since
  $$\lim_{r \to +\infty}\left| -\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^r_{t_0} \right| = \infty$$

---

In this case
$$\lim_{r \to +\infty}-\dfrac{1}{s} \left[ e^{-st} \right]^r_{t_0}=\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0}$$

This yields the formula
$$\int_{t_0}^\infty e^{-st}dt =\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0} \qquad \mbox{ for }  \mbox{Re}(s) >0 \,.$$

Remember that, whenever we speak about the Laplace trasnform, the formula we get holds over the region of convergence. It is always important to emphasize/state what this region is, but this is often lost in a side note.

Comment: Why do we only focus on the real part of $s$?

Comment: @ThePointer Check the edit. The reason why we can focus on it is because  $$\left| e^{-st} \right|= e^{-\mbox{Re}(s) t}$$ which converges to $0$ or infinity when $\mbox{Re}(s)>0$ and $\mbox{Re}(s)<0$ respectively. This immediately implies convergence, and divergence, in these cases.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\left(\cos( -\mbox{Im}(s)r)+i \sin(-\mbox{Im}(s)r) \right)$?

Comment: Which that? Note that $\left(\cos( -\mbox{Im}(s)r)+i \sin(-\mbox{Im}(s)r) \right)$ has modulus 1.

Comment: $$\lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s}  e^{-sr} = \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-(x + iy)r} = \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-(x)r}e^{-(iy)r} = \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-(x)r}e^{i(-yr)} = \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-(x)r} \left(\cos(-yr) + i \sin(-yr) \right) = \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-(x)r} \left(\cos( -\mbox{Im}(s)r)+i \sin(-\mbox{Im}(s)r) \right)$$

Comment: My point is that you wrote $$\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-s t_0}- \lim_{r \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{s}  e^{-\mbox{Re}{(s)}r} \left(\cos( -\mbox{Im}(r)s)+i \sin(-\mbox{Im}(r)s) \right)$$ after the "**Added** [ Details," part.

Comment: @ThePointer Yes, you are right. Typo.

Comment: And the third case: $\mbox{Re}{(s)} >0$; you meant $\mbox{Re}{(s)} < 0$?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for taking the time to post this informative answer!