# Laplace transform of $\cosh(t)$ from first principles: How to deal with infinities?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm trying to find the Laplace transform of $\cosh(t)$ from first principles. My work is as follows:

$$\begin{align} \mathcal{L}\{\cosh(t)\} &= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \cosh(t) \ dt \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \left( \dfrac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2} \right) \ dt \ \ \text{(Using the definition of $\cosh(t)$.)} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{t - st} \ dt + \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-t - st} \ dt \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \lim_{t_1 \to \infty - s\infty} \int_0^{t_1} e^{u_1} \ du_1 + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \lim_{t_2 \to -\infty - s\infty} \int_0^{t_2} e^{u_2} \ du_2  \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \lim_{t_1 \to \infty - s\infty} \left[ e^{u_1} \right]^{t_1}_0 + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \lim_{t_2 \to -\infty - s\infty} \left[ e^{u_2} \right]^{t_2}_0 \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left[ e^{\infty - s\infty} - 1 \right] + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \left[ e^{-\infty - s\infty} - 1  \right] \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left[ e^{\infty} e^{-s \infty} - 1 \right] + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \left[ e^{-\infty} e^{- s\infty} - 1  \right] \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left[ e^{\infty} e^{-\infty (x + iy)} - 1 \right] + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \left[ e^{-\infty} e^{-\infty (x + iy)} - 1  \right] \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left[ e^{\infty} e^{-\infty x} e^{-\infty iy} - 1 \right] + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \left[ e^{-\infty} e^{-\infty x} e^{-\infty iy} - 1  \right] \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left\{ e^{\infty} e^{-\infty x} \cos[(- \infty y) + i \sin(- \infty y)] - 1 \right\} + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \left\{ e^{-\infty} e^{-\infty x} \cos[(- \infty y) + i \sin(- \infty y)] - 1  \right\} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left\{ e^{\infty} e^{-\infty x} \cos[(- \infty y) + i \sin(- \infty y)] - 1 \right\} + \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \left\{ \dfrac{1}{e^{\infty x} e^{\infty}} \cos[(- \infty y) + i \sin(- \infty y)] - 1  \right\} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left\{ e^{\infty} e^{-\infty x} \cos[(- \infty y) + i \sin(- \infty y)] - 1 \right\} - \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2(1 - s)} \left\{ \dfrac{e^{\infty}}{e^{\infty x}} \cos[(- \infty y) + i \sin(- \infty y)] \right\} - \dfrac{1}{2(-1 - s)} \end{align}$$

I know that, by the theory of Laplace transforms, we require that $\Re(s) > 0$. However, I'm still unsure of how to deal with the term with $\dfrac{e^{\infty}}{e^{\infty x}}$? How does this lead to a solution?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Calculations like this with $\infty$ in there are not valid.

Comment: @GEdgar Hold on, I undeleted this and am trying to edit with additional calculations. The edit preview isn't showing up, which makes it difficult to coordinate edits.

Comment: You need to assume that $\Re(s) > 1$, the integral doesn't converge for the other $s$.

Comment: @reuns Hmm? I was under the impression that it was $\Re(s) > 0$?

Comment: You have $\int e^{t-st} dt$ in the beginning. So, the condition required for the convergence of the integral should be obvious from that.

Comment: @GEdgar Ok, all done! Sorry about that.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Hmm, why should it be obvious? This is a problem from the first chapter of my textbook, so we haven't yet delved into the complex analysis behind Laplace transforms. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are OK up to here:
$$
\dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{t - st} \ dt + \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-t - st} \ dt
$$
Now go like this:
$$
\int_0^M e^{t-st}\;dt = \frac{1}{1-s}e^{t-st}\big|_{t=0}^M
=\frac{e^{M(1-s)}}{1-s}-\frac{1}{1-s}
\\
\int_0^\infty e^{t-st}\;dt = \lim_{M \to \infty}
\left(\frac{e^{M(1-s)}}{1-s}-\frac{1}{1-s}\right) = \frac{-1}{1-s}
\qquad\text{(assuming $\mathrm{Re}\;s>1$)}
$$
And similarly for the other one
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-t-st}\;dt = \lim_{M \to \infty} \left(\frac{-e^{-M(s+1)}}{1+s}+\frac{1}{1+s}\right) = \frac{1}{1+s}\qquad\text{(assuming $\mathrm{Re}\;s>-1$)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please elaborate on why we have $\Re(s) > 1$ and $\Re(s) >  -1$, instead of $\Re(s) > 0$?

Comment: For the limits.  $\lim_{M \to \infty} e^{aM}= 0$ only if $\mathrm{Re}\; a<0$. In those two cases $a$ is $1-s$ and $-1-s$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I had some incorrect misconceptions that were preventing me from understanding this concept. In this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3242975/356308 answer to one of my past Laplace transform questions, the user N. S. demonstrate that we require $\Re(s) > 0$ for convergence of the integral $\int_{t_0}^\infty e^{-st}dt$. However, in this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3367142/356308 answer to another one of my past Laplace transform questions, the [...]

Comment: [...] user copper.hat states that we require $\Re(s - k) > 0$ for convergence of the more general integral $\int_0^\infty e^{- (s-k)t} dt$. So, for the current case, we have that $\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1 + s)} \ dt$, which requires $\Re(1 + s) > 0$, which implies that we require $\Re(s) > -1$, and $\int_0^\infty e^{t(1 - s)} \ dt$, which requires $\Re(1 - s) < 0$, which implies that we require $\Re(s) > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is bounded or integrable then $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$. For other kind of functions everything can happen. In most cases you'll need to find the least $c$ such that $\int_0^\infty |f(t)e^{-(c+\epsilon)t}|dt<\infty$, then you'll consider $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$ only for $\Re(s) > c$.

> Here $c=1$

The abscissa of convergence theorem (which follows from an integration by parts) is that if $f$ is locally integrable and $\lim_{T\to \infty}\int_0^T f(t)e^{-\sigma t}dt$ converges then $\lim_{T\to \infty}\int_0^T f(t)e^{-s t}dt$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > \sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1. But don't we have that $f(t) = \cosh(t)$ in this case? What's so different about this? 2. This looks very similar to the requirement that $f(t)$ be of exponential order?

Comment: I can't guess what you don't understand. Do you see why this answers your problem ? Sure if $f$ has at most exponential growth then $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$ converges absolutely and is analytic for $\Re(s)$ large enough.

Comment: You said that, if $f$ is bounded or integrable, then $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \ dt$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$, and for other kinds of functions, everything can happen. So it seems that you are implying that my case of having the function $f(t) = \cosh(t)$ is one of those "other" kinds of functions? But I don't see what's different about the case $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$ that you presented, and my case of $\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \cosh(t) \ dt$? This is just the case $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \ dt$ that you presented, with $f(t) = \cosh(t)$.